AVPlayerItemVideoOutput lack of memory
I am developing an app for Vision Pro that plays videos.
I am using AVFoundation as the video playback framework, and I have implemented a process to extract video frames using AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.
The videos to be played are in 8K and 16K resolutions, but when AVPlayerItemVideoOutput is set and I try to play the 16K video, it does not play, and I receive the error "Cannot Complete Action."

When not using AVPlayerItemVideoOutput:

8K: ✅ Plays

16K: ✅ Plays



When using AVPlayerItemVideoOutput:

8K: ✅ Plays

16K: ❌ Does not play




The AVPlayerItemVideoOutput settings are as follows:
      private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? {
        didSet {
            playerItemObserver = playerItem?.observe(\AVPlayerItem.status, options: [.new, .initial]) { [weak self] (item, _) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                if item.status == .readyToPlay {
                  let videoColorProperties = [
                    AVVideoColorPrimariesKey: AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2,
                    AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2,
                    AVVideoYCbCrMatrixKey: AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2]        
                  let outputVideoSettings = [
                    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange,
                    AVVideoColorPropertiesKey: videoColorProperties,
                    kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey as String: true
                  ] as [String: Any]
                  strongSelf.videoPlayerOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(outputSettings: outputVideoSettings)
                  strongSelf.playerItem!.add(strongSelf.videoPlayerOutput!)

We checked VisionPro's memory usage during 8K and 16K playback when using AVPlayerItemVideoOutput and found that it is 62% for 8K playback and 84% for 16K playback, and we expect that the difference in resolution per frame affects the memory usage, making 16K playback The difference in resolution per frame affects memory usage, and we expect that 16K playback is no longer possible.
We would appreciate any insight into memory management and efficiency when using AVFounation / AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.
